# Error trying to publish on nativescript sidekick

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Everytime I'm trying to publish an app with sidekick I'm getting the same error:

```
--> starting at object with constructor 'Error'
--- property 'errors' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:778:25)
at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:676:19)
at MessageService.sendMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/message-service.js:34:21)
at sendMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:13:24)
at sendErrorMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:19:9)
at /opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:36:17
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning (internal/process/promises.js:141:15)
at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:203:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)

(CLI) (node:17346) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Error'
--- property 'errors' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:778:25)
at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:676:19)
at MessageService.sendMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/message-service.js:34:21)
at sendMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:13:24)
at sendErrorMessage (/opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:19:9)
at /opt/NativeScript Sidekick/resources/app.asar.unpacked/shared/child-process/child-helpers.js:36:17
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:17346) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
at emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:153:11)
at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:205:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
```

Version: 1.19.2-v.2019.11.18.2 (latest)
NativeScript CLI version: 6.2.2
CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.19.3
CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

node: v12.13.1

I've tried downgrade the node verson, to 10.12.0, still getting the same error